# How to print the innerText of a <div> element in Angular 7 that works on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, bulma

I was working on a personal project where I wanted to have a button to print the content of a `<div>` element. Things were working on desktop, but somehow it fails to print on mobile devices with the text *"There was a problem printing the page. Please try again."* No error or warning reported on Chrome Developer Tools when inspecting on desktop. Here is the code I am using:

Part of App.component.html :

```
  <div id="1">
      <h3 class="title">Some Title</h3>
      <p class="subtitle">Some Text</p>
      <a id="1-print">Print</a>
  </div>
```

Part of App.component.ts :

```
  const printQuote = (id) => {
      const content = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
      const printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');

      printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
      printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
      printWindow.document.write('<h1>QuotesWorld</h1>');
      printWindow.document.write(content);
      printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

      printWindow.document.close();
      printWindow.focus();
      printWindow.print();
      printWindow.close();
  };

  const printArr = ['1-print', '2-print', '3-print', '4-print', '5-print',
                    '6-print', '7-print', '8-print', '9-print', '10-print',
                    '11-print', '12-print', '13-print', '14-print', '15-print',
                    '16-print', '17-print', '18-print', '19-print', '20-print',
                    ... '55-print', '56-print'];

  const quotArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 56; i++) {
      quotArr[i] = i + 1;
      document.getElementById(printArr[i]).addEventListener('click', () => {
          printQuote(quotArr[i]); 
      });
  }
```

When a desktop user clicks on the element, it opens up a new window with a print dialog however, it results in an error on mobile devices. Help appreciated :)

Comment: _"it results in an error on mobile devices"_ - what error?

Comment: @lucifer63 Print Dialog on Chrome (Android) shows _"There was a problem printing the page. Please try again."_ No error or warning reported on Chrome Developer Tools when inspecting on my desktop, it works if I inspect it on desktop. It throws the above error on mobile devices. Tried it on various devices, same error.

Answer (score 0):

i have not used this features but i think the problem is with the width and height you provided for window size here:

```
const printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
```

try to create smaller window for mobile devices.